# Custom equality_check function for perfplot

Tags: python, performance, equality, perfplot

I'm working with the perfplot library to compare the performance of three functions `f1`, `f2` and `f3`. The functions are supposed to return the same values, so I want to do equality checks. However, all other examples of perfplot I can find on the internet use `pd.DataFrame.equals` or `np.allclose` as an equality checker but these don't work for my specific case.

For example, `np.allclose` wouldn't work if the functions return a list of numpy arrays of different lengths.

```py
import perfplot
import numpy as np

def f1(rng):
    return [np.array(range(i)) for i in rng]

def f2(rng):
    return [np.array(list(rng)[:i]) for i in range(len(rng))]

def f3(rng):
    return [np.array([*range(i)]) for i in rng]


perfplot.show(
    kernels=[f1, f2, f3],
    n_range=[10**k for k in range(4)],
    setup=lambda n: range(n),
    equality_check=np.allclose   # <-- doesn't work; neither does pd.DataFrame.equals
)
```

How do I pass a function that is different from the aforementioned functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we inspect the [source code](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot/blob/main/src/perfplot/_main.py), the way the equality check works is that it takes the output of the first function passed to `kernels` as reference and compares it to the output of the subsequent functions passed to `kernels` in a loop.

For some reason, the equality check is different depending on if the first function in `kernels` returns a tuple or not.

If the first function in `kernels` doesn't returns a tuple, it simply calls the function passed to `equality_check` argument to perform the check. The equality check function takes two arguments and can do whatever. For example, it can only check if the lengths are equal and call it a day (i.e. pass the following lambda to `equality_check`: `lambda x,y: len(x) == len(y)`).

For the example in the question, a function that loops over pairs of elements and checks for inequality works.

```py
def equality_check(x, y):
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        if not np.allclose(i, j):
            return False
    return True

perfplot.show(
    kernels=[f1, f2, f3],
    n_range=[10**k for k in range(4)],
    setup=lambda n: range(n),
    equality_check=equality_check
)
```

In fact, `all()` also works.

```py
perfplot.show(
    kernels=[f1, f2, f3],
    n_range=[10**k for k in range(4)],
    setup=lambda n: range(1, n+1),
    equality_check=lambda x,y: all([x,y])
)
```

---

The following code copied from the [source code](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot/blob/main/src/perfplot/_main.py#L233-L288) is the snippet that implements the equality check:

```py
for k, kernel in enumerate(self.kernels):

    val = kernel(*data)

    if self.equality_check:
        if k == 0:
            reference = val
        else:
            try:
                if isinstance(reference, tuple):
                    assert isinstance(val, tuple)
                    assert len(reference) == len(val)
                    is_equal = True
                    for r, v in zip(reference, val):
                        if not self.equality_check(r, v):
                            is_equal = False
                            break
                else:
                    is_equal = self.equality_check(reference, val)
            except TypeError:
                raise PerfplotError(
                    "Error in equality_check. "
                    + "Try setting equality_check=None."
                )
            else:
                if not is_equal:
                    raise PerfplotError(
                        "Equality check failure.\n"
                        + f"{self.labels[0]}:\n"
                        + f"{reference}:\n\n"
                        + f"{self.labels[k]}:\n"
                        + f"{val}:\n"
                    )
```